# Finding the limit $ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1-3x)^\frac{1}{3} -(1-2x)^\frac{1}{2}}{1-\cos(\pi x)}$

Tags: limits

I cannot find this limit: 
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1-3x)^\frac{1}{3} -(1-2x)^\frac{1}{2}}{1-\cos(\pi x)}.
$$
Please, help me.

Upd: I need to solve it without L'Hôpital's Rule and Taylor expansion.

Comment: Taylor expansion to second order helps.

Comment: You can also use LHopital rule

Comment: @DanielFischer Asking to to this without Taylor expansion this should be considered torture, therefore banned by the Geneva convention.

Comment: Ok, I saw your update after I posted my answer. Too bad, since I'm afraid that I agree with egreg: this exercise without l'H and/or Taylor expansions and chemical weapons should be allowed only in cases of extremely terrible students.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @freak_warrior yes, it is. I have been trying to do this task for hours =( I cannot use l'H and Taylor because we didnot learn it.

Comment: @user109428: So what have you all learned? Can you show us?

Comment: we have learned some basic things of finding limits of sequences and functions. The last theme was about limits of special interest.

Answer (score 4):

Write it as $\left(\frac{\cos\pi x-\cos0}{x-0}\right)^{-1}\times\frac{\left(1-3x\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-\left(1-2x\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{x-0}$.

Then $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\cos\pi x-\cos0}{x-0}$ can be recognized
as $f'\left(0\right)$ for $f\left(x\right)=\cos\pi x$

and $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\left(1-3x\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-\left(1-2x\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{x-0}$
as $g'\left(0\right)$ for $g\left(x\right)=\left(1-3x\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-\left(1-2x\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

If you are blamed to use de l'Hôpital after all then just claim that
you were not aware of that. They will believe you.

**Edit:**

This only works if $f'\left(0\right)\neq0$ and unfortunately
that is not the case here.

So to be honest: this does not answer your question. Keep it in mind
however for next occasions.

Comment: This expresses the limit as $f'(0)/g'(0)$ for some functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f'(0)=g'(0)=0$. (Nice upvotes though, would you have a fan club?)

Comment: @did Sigh... I did not bother to look at the outcomes. Now what to do? Delete it and throw away my upvotes? I think people liked it especially because of the sneaky use of l'Hopital. I will make an edit. Fanclub... I enjoy the thought.

Comment: I would say you got upvotes because of the "They will believe you" part (which is nice, mind you) and because many voters simply do not read/master/check the maths. Anyway, you are not responsible for that and, with the Edit, there is nothing to say against your post.

Answer (score 3):

Solving this without Taylor expansion is quite artificial, if you ask me (any justification, pedagogical or otherwise?), hence here we go for artificiality.

If $u\to1$ and $v\to1$,
$$
u^{1/6}-v^{1/6}=\frac{u-v}{u^{5/6}+u^{4/6}v^{1/6}+u^{3/6}v^{2/6}+u^{2/6}v^{3/6}+u^{1/6}v^{4/6}+v^{5/6}},
$$
and each term in the denominator has limit $1$ hence
$$
u^{1/6}-v^{1/6}\sim\frac{u-v}6.
$$
Using this for $u=(1-3x)^2$ and $v=(1-2x)^3$ yields $u-v=-3x^2+8x^3$ hence 
$$u-v\sim-3x^2.
$$
On the other hand, $1-\cos(\pi x)=2\sin^2\left(\frac12\pi x\right)$ and $\sin t\sim t$ (*but are we allowed to use this? this is Taylor, after all...*) hence 
$$1-\cos(\pi x)\sim2\left(\frac12\pi x\right)^2=\frac12\pi^2x^2.$$
Thus, the limit of the ratio is
$$
\frac{-3\cdot\frac16}{\frac12\pi^2}=-\frac1{\pi^2}.
$$

Comment: There is a $\frac{1}{6}$ missing in exponents of the denominator.

Comment: @Xoff Right, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

l'Hospital:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1-3x)^{1/3}-(1-2x)^{1/2}}{1-\cos \pi x}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-(1-3x)^{-2/3}+(1-2x)^{-1/2}}{\pi\sin\pi x}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=$$

$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-2(1-3x)^{-5/3}+(1-2x)^{-3/2}}{\pi^2\cos\pi x}=-\frac1{\pi^2}$$

Comment: OP stated no LHopital

Comment: Yes, he did...after or while I wrote and posted my answer. It stays in case someone wants to check how to do it without being forced to sell one's soul to some god or devil.

Comment: @freak_warrior But this is l'Hospital

Answer (score 1):

Your limit is 
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(1-3x)^\frac{1}{3}-(1-2x)^{\frac{1}{2} } }{1-\cos\pi x }$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(1-3x)^\frac{1}{3}-(1-2x)^{\frac{1}{2} } }{1-\cos\pi x }\cdot \frac{1+\cos(\pi x)}{1+\cos(\pi x)}$$ 
$$=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\left((1-3x)^\frac{1}{3}-(1-2x)^{\frac{1}{2} }\right)(1+\cos(\pi x)) }{1-\cos^2\pi x }$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\left((1-3x)^\frac{1}{3}-(1-2x)^{\frac{1}{2} }\right)(1+\cos(\pi x)) }{\sin^2\pi x }$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\left((1-3x)^\frac{2}{3}-(1-2x)\right)(1+\cos(\pi x)) }{\left((1-3x)^\frac{1}{3}+(1-2x)^{\frac{1}{2} }\right)\sin^2\pi x } $$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\left((1-3x)^\frac{2}{3}-(1-2x)\right) }{\sin^2\pi x } $$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\left((1-3x)^{2}-(1-2x)^3\right) }{(P(x))\sin^2\pi x } $$
$\lim_{x\to 0} P(x)=3$. Here $P(x)=(1-3x)^{\frac{4}{3}}+(1-3x)^{\frac{1}{3}}(1-2x)+(1-2x)^2$.
Now, $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\left((1-3x)^{2}-(1-2x)^3\right) }{\sin^2\pi x }=-\frac{3}{\pi^2}$$ because 
$$=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\frac{(1-3x)^{2}-(1-2x)^3}{\pi^2 x^2} }{\frac{\sin^2\pi x}{\pi^2 x^2}}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(1-3x)^{2}-(1-2x)^3}{\pi^2 x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{8x^3-3x^2}{\pi^2 x^2}=-\frac{3}{\pi^2}$$
Thus your limit is equal to
$$\frac{-3}{\pi^2}\cdot \frac{1}{3}=-\frac{1}{\pi^2}$$

Comment: In this proof i use several facts: $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$. If $\lim fg$ exist an $\lim g$ exist then $\lim f$ also exist.

Comment: "If lim fg exist(s) an(d) lim g exist(s) then lim f also exist(s)". Sure about this one?

Comment: You rigth. And $\lim g(x)\neq 0$ And if $g(x)\neq 0$ for all $x$ near to $0$ in this case.

Comment: Rather, if lim g is not zero.